React Hook Form defaultValues NOT updating when navigating to a new route with React Router Data Loader
I have a Product component that uses a data Loader with the useLoaderData hook from React Router. The component contains a React Hook Form with the useForm hook and I am passing in defaultValues for the form with data from the loader. Now when I navigate to a DIFFERENT Product path ("/product/productId1" -> "/product/productId2"), the react hook form is still using the defaultValues provided from productId1.
Here is what my component looks like:
export const Product = (props) => {
  const data = useLoaderData();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const formMethods = useForm({ defaultValues: data });

  return <...>
}

I think this is happening because the useForm hook persists between renders even though data has already updated. If I use the reloadDocument option when navigating, the defaultValues data is updated but I don't want to reload the whole document.
Would it make sense to put the useForm hook inside a useEffect that depends on the data from the loader?


I think this is happening because the useForm hook persists between
renders even though data has already updated.

Yes, the useForm hook state persists because the Product component remains mounted while the only the route path params update, e.g. while the "/product/:productId" route is still matched and rendered.

Would it make sense to put the useForm hook inside a useEffect that
depends on the data from the loader?

Your thinking is on the right track, though you can not call any React hooks from the use useEffect callback as this breaks the Rules of Hooks, e.g. "Do not call Hooks inside functions passed to useMemo, useReducer, or useEffect".
You can reset the form data when the loaded data value updates.
Basic Example:
export const Product = (props) => {
  const data = useLoaderData();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const formMethods = useForm({ defaultValues: data });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      formMethods.reset(data, /* any reset options */);
    }
  }, [data]);

  return <...>
};

